# How to exclude one object type from a Linq query

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4

For one on my unit test I am developping a linq query that retrieves all the controllers types from a MVC project and make sure it inherits from a BaseController.

```
var controllers = typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly.GetTypes().Where(typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom);
```

How can I remove from this list the BaseController object? I have tried several things but it always remove from the list all the controllers that do not inherits from BaseController.

Here is the unit test

```
[Fact]
    public void All_Controllers_Inherit_From_BaseController()
    {
        var controllers = typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly.GetTypes().Where(typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom);

        foreach (var controller in controllers)
        {
            Assert.True(controller.BaseType == typeof(BaseController));
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, two options spring to mind:

- Explicitly "remove" `BaseController` using `Except`:

  ```
  var controllers = typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly
                            .GetTypes()
                            .Except(new[] { typeof(BaseController) })
                            .Where(typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom);
  ```
- Only consider concrete types; I assume `BaseController` is abstract:

  ```
  var controllers = typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly
                            .GetTypes()
                            .Where(type => !type.IsAbstract)
                            .Where(typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom);
  ```